# How to select the items with foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below there are my tables. On login, I want to select all messages who belong for example to `user` with `id = 1`.
I have tried something like this but it doesn't work, `select id from users where users.id = message_sent.id_user`

The error I got is:
`#1054 - Unknown column 'message_sent.id_user' in 'where clause'`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Ok I am gonna change it to a text format.

Comment: You need to put message_sent in a FROM clause, to access its columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is called a `join`.

In your case: `SELECT id FROM users JOIN message_sent ON users.id = message_sent.id_user`

**Tip**

I see that you use incremental counters as an id for your rows. This is a really bad idea. You should never ever use incremental counters. Where is why:

- A person can just loop trough your users or messages with a script.
- People can just count how many users you have

please take a look at this: https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8?t=119

You should just use a random generated string or number (also explained in the video). See if it is taken. If it isn't taken use it. This isn't to much work and improves the security on your site!

Comment: Thank you so much you remembered me that this is a `join`,and I found the solution `SELECT users.username , message_sent.name FROM message_sent INNER JOIN users ON message_sent.id_user = users.id`

Comment: No problem! But please take a look at my tip!  This will greatly improve the security on your site! @Viorel

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding auto increment, I didn't know that. I will keep in mind.